# How to drop table in SQLite Kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I want to drop a table in SQLite, but it doesn't work.

My code right now looks like this

```
val db = this.writableDatabase
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_NAME)
db.close()
```

I've tried rawQuery but that doesn't work either. My app crashes when I press a button that uses this function.

Comment: whats the error you get

Comment: if TABLE_NAME is input by an end user you need to be careful with sql injection

Comment: i dont get an error, the app simply crashes. TABLE_NAME is an value assigned at the top of the document, so nog userinput here.

Comment: Try `"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"`, probably you try to delete a table that was not created yet. Also there should be logcat output.

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` also doesn't work. Where can I see logcat output?

Comment: @ArnovanLiere copy logcat from android studio and add it here

Comment: how do you get logcat?

Comment: logcat is in bottom of android studio in "android monitor" tab

Comment: I run the app on my phone by the way, emulator doesn't work, I don't have hardware acceleration

Comment: plug your mobile to pc and debug your app with android studio

Comment: E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "EXISTSPasswordManager": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nl.arnovanliere.www.dbtest, PID: 2269
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXISTSPasswordManager": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTSPasswordManager

Comment: perhaps missed a space after `EXISTS`?

Comment: nope, thats not the problem. Added space after `EXISTS`, but the app still crashes

Comment: add stack trace to your question not in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have syntax error in SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTSPasswordManager
```

the error word is:

```
EXISTSPasswordManager
```

add space before `PasswordManager` and after `EXISTS`

Comment: PasswordManager is the tablename, so without tablename the query is invalid i guess?

Comment: @ArnovanLiere sorry i meant adding space

Comment: `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  " + TABLE_NAME)` still doesn't work

Comment: @ArnovanLiere and what is stack trace? you can not correct an error without seeing stack trace unless you know the problem in advance

Comment: It works, thanks!!! Also thanks for showing how to use the logcat, it solved my problem. Thanks @BAHMAN